# Get error: `../node_modules/electron/index.js:1:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'` when I use next.js with electron template

Tags: typescript, next.js, electron

I use next.js with electron template,

I want to import ipcRenderer in   pages/index.tsx,

the key code:

```
...
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';


function Home() {

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on("getMember-reply", (event, data) => {
      console.log(data); 
    });
    return () => {                     
      ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("getMember-reply");
    };
  }, [])

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      ipcRenderer.send("getMember", {});     
    }else {
      return
    }
  }

  return (
   <>
    <h1>home</h1>
    <Button onClick={handleClick}> Click Me</Button>
   </>

  );
};

export default Home;
```

when I run `npm run dev` I get issue as below:

```
../node_modules/electron/index.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/home/index.tsx
```

[image]

#### Example

My demo code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/t97jc3

Answer (score -1):

Recheck the module path again if that implemented properly and also recheck whether used `var fs = require('fs');` on your file.

Comment: no, I didn't use it.